# Rerender all h:inputText fields with same id inside h:dataTable

Tags: ajax, jsf

I think I am wasting my time yet again figuring out how to do such a simple thing in JSF, but assuming the following set-up:

```
 <h:form id="form">
    <h:dataTable id="table">
        <! -- not shown: other columns with other input fields -->
        <h:column>
          <h:inputText id="myinput">
                <f:ajax execute="@this" render="????" listener="#{bean.action}" />
          </h:inputText> 
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

What do I specify in the render tag to ONLY re-render all "myinput" components across all rows in the datatable, ie without specifying "@form" that will re-render the other components as well? I have tried @this and ":form:table:myinput", but it always just re-renders the very first row of the dataTable. It seems like this should be such a simple use-case, so I have to obviously be misunderstanding something.

Note: I don't know if internally JSF creates N HtmlInputTextComponents for each row or just 1, but obviously when I say "all myinput components", I mean all rendered input fields back to the browser that were generated from the h:inputText tag and that have the same browser DOM id of form:table:myinput:n.

As a corollary and additional question, I don't want to process or re-render the whole form components because of possible validation/conversion errors. I simply want the following to happen: only the initiating "myinput" component that triggered the ajax call is validated, and if success, all of the other "myinput" components are populated and subsequently re-rendered with new model values that were changed from the action listener "#{bean.action}".

Additional information:
I am currently using the mojarra implementation version of JSF 2.1 (I think). I would like to avoid any third party JSF libraries.

Bonus questions (which perhaps the answer to my original question would also answer):

> 1. How to re-render and/or execute all input components but only for a single row
> 2. How to re-render and/or execute set of input components but only for a single row
> 3. How to re-render and/or execute all input components for a set of rows (not all)
> 4. How to re-render and/or execute set of input components for a set of rows (not all)

**To everyone replying that I can set the id of the inputText based upon the current rowIndex or current iteration variable - NO, that does not work.** See: [Set id of a component within JSF dataTable to value from current item in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660969/set-id-of-a-component-within-jsf-datatable-to-value-from-current-item-in-the-arr)

I really think the only way to accomplish what I want is to abandon using a datatable and render the table columns/rpws with JSTL myself such that I can assign unique ids and have full control. However, I still think this is a huge design flaw in JSF to not support such a seemingly simple use-case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *What do I specify in the render tag to ONLY re-render all "myinput" components across all rows in the datatable, ie without specifying "@form" that will re-render the other components as well?*
>
> TL;DR: *How do I re-render the entire column?*

This is not possible using standard JSF facilities. You basically need to (auto)generate the collection of client IDs `form:table:0:myinput`, `form:table:1:myinput`, `form:table:2:myinput`, etc yourself based on row count/index, and manually add them all to the [`PartialViewContext#getRenderIds()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/PartialViewContext.html#getRenderIds()) collection during `#{bean.action}`. It's not possible to specify them in `render` attribute as those client IDs don't exist in JSF component tree, [but JSF strictly wants to validate them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/cannot-find-component-with-expression-foo-referenced-from-bar-fajax-con) (and you thus end up with confusing "cannot find client ID" exceptions).

I'm aware that you want to avoid 3rd party libraries, but [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`Ajax#updateColumn()`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Ajax) provides exactly this functionality which only takes the table component and the (zero-based) column index as arguments. E.g.

```
public void action() {
    // ...
    UIData table = Components.findComponent("form:table");
    Ajax.updateColumn(table, 2); // Updates third column.
}
```

Feel free to borrow/steal/improve the [source](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.0/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/util/Ajax.java#L188) under Apache 2.0 license if the remainder of OmniFaces isn't sufficiently convenient to not anymore consider it as an "average" 3rd party library.

We have by the way a possible enhancement in the queue for a future OmniFaces release, which must make this kind of requirements more hair-friendly: [event driven updates](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/69).

---

> - *How to re-render and/or execute all input components but only for a single row?*
> - *How to re-render and/or execute set of input components but only for a single row?*

You can specify them in `render` attribute using relative client IDs like so:

```html
<h:column><h:inputText id="input1" ... /></h:column>
<h:column><h:inputText id="input2" ... /></h:column>
<h:column><h:inputText id="input3" ... /></h:column>
<h:column><h:inputText id="input4" ...><f:ajax render="input1 input2 input3" ... /></h:inputText></h:column>
```

Note: there's no way to explicitly say "all input components". You'd have to specify them individually. If you happen to use PrimeFaces, or are open to using it, then [PrimeFaces Selectors](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/selector.xhtml) would make this much easier. See also among others [How do PrimeFaces Selectors as in update="@(.myClass)" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080861/how-do-primefaces-selectors-as-in-update-myclass-work)

---

> - *How to re-render and/or execute all input components for a set of rows (not all)*
> - *How to re-render and/or execute set of input components for a set of rows (not all)*

Also here, no standard facility. You could extend on the aforementioned `Ajax#updateColumn()` source code. The key problem is that you wanted to update *other* rows as well than only the current row. For that you'd really need to (auto)generate full client IDs and add them to `PartialViewContext#getRenderIds()`.

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling that it would be you that would end up providing a sufficient answer to this question. I had no idea about PartialViewContext#getRenderIds() and will look into Omnifaces. Maybe these features will become a standard in the next major revision of JSF, ie JSF 3.0 hopefully!!?

Comment: Why can't OP just ajax-update the column containing the input components?

Answer (score -2):

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:dataTable id="table" rowIndexVar="idx">
        <! -- not shown: other columns with other input fields -->
        <h:column>
          <h:inputText id="myinput#{idx.index}">
                <f:ajax execute="@this" render="????" listener="#{bean.action}" />
          </h:inputText> 
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

using firebug, you can see that all your inputs have an id now. Now, you can put in your render what you want according to this id.

you must use

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(lstIndex);
```

in your java code where **lstIndex** is the list of ids that you want to update

Comment: Does not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660969/set-id-of-a-component-within-jsf-datatable-to-value-from-current-item-in-the-arr